# Does opening the Mac mini 2018 for cleaning void the warranty?

Tags: mac, hardware, mac-mini, warranty, macos

I've had my Mac mini 2018 for just over two years. I am concerned that there has accumulated dust inside of the computer – not because anything seems problematic at the moment, but my experience with MacBook Pro laptops has been that you need to clean them every two years. There is usually a dust coasting landing on top of the Mac mini, so I am suspecting it needs to be cleaned also.

If I were to open the Mac mini and attempt to blow it clean with compressed air, would that void any remaining warranty?

NB: I believe my product is actually already outside of Apple's limited warranty. However, does Apple not want consumers to open the Mac Mini, so that if something were to break at some time, that an authorized service shop would refuse repair?

Comment: Bear in mind that "Apple's warranty" and "your statutory rights" are two different things. Also, if Apple didn't want users opening the lid on the back, they would have screwed it down with non-standard screws.

Answer (score 2):

The [iFixit Teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+mini+Late+2018+Teardown/115210) shows the Mac mini 2018 is relatively easy to open.

Apple even returned to the user replaceable RAM option, thus indicating that they expect users to open the case. Unless you start digging around and removing components (other than RAM) I don't think you'll be in any danger.

As always, make sure you follow proper ESD procedures to protect the logic board & RAM from getting zapped by static electricity.